# Wide spacing (underfull lines) in bibliography entries

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

My bibliography entry looks like

[image: this].

I would like to reduce the space of the title to a reasonable size. The only code I have that concerns the bibliography is:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{bibl}
```

Edit: I actually forgot to add my bibliography entry:

```
@misc{left_pad,
    title = {NPM \& left-pad: Have We Forgotten How To Program?},
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/}},
}
```

Comment: Adding `\url` to web page should help. I.e. `\url{http://www....}`.

Comment: Make sure to load the `url ` package with the option `hyphens`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able the replicate the look of your screenshot with the following MWE; the main parameter setting I had to guess was `\textwidth=10cm`. (`4in` would do as well, I suppose.)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibl.bib}
@misc{left_pad,
    title = {{NPM} \& left-pad: Have We Forgotten How To Program?},
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\setlength\textwidth{10cm}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibl}
\end{document}
```

To fix the problem of the massively under-full middle line, it suffices to add the option `hyphens` when loading the `url` package: `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`. Indeed, the only difference between the two MWEs is the presence of the `hyphens` option for loading `url`; I trust you will agree that the look of the bibliographic entry is much improved.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibl.bib}
@misc{left_pad,
    title = {{NPM} \& left-pad: Have We Forgotten How To Program?},
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % <-- crucial: specify the option "hyphens"
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\setlength\textwidth{10cm}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibl}
\end{document}
```